# How to delete SharePoint Site Collection using pnp csom programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have a requirement on SharePoint Online Office 365. As per my requirement, I have to delete all the Site Collection from SharePoint Online Office 365 Admin Center using pnp csom programmatically.

Anyone can suggest that how can I delete all the Site Collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DeleteSiteCollection` extension method to remove the site collection.

It can be used as below:

```
string userName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "password";

string siteUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);

    // use false, if you want to keep site collection in recycle bin
    tenant.DeleteSiteCollection("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test", true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to SharePoint Online with global administrator account:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Remove specific site collection by url:

```
Remove-PnPTenantSite -Url   https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename-Force -SkipRecycleBin
```

[Remove-PnPTenantSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps)