# Is it possible to set a property bag value via CSOM without having tenant permissions?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-online, csom, propertybag

I'm trying to use my backend CSOM app with context of Site Collection Administrator service account to programmatically set a property bag value to store some settings for my frontend extension app.

I've tried doing it in 2 ways:

```
web.SetPropertyBagValue("name", "value");
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

and

```
web.AllProperties["name"] = "value";
web.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

but in both cases I get the error:

> {"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
> access this resource."}

Is there really no way a Site Collection Administrator could set a property bag in SharePoint Online? I'm asking this because I've had similar issue when trying to delete a site, in which case according to [a few](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228076/delete-sharepoint-online-site-programmatically) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722180/how-to-delete-sharepoint-site-collection-using-pnp-csom-programmatically) on the Internet this operation could also be done only by tenant administrator but I found a method:

```
ctx.DeleteSiteAsync()
```

which turned out to be successfully deleting a site without tenant permissions. So I hope maybe there is also a solution here.

Comment: This is doable. I assume your likely using a Modern site? These have noscript enabled by default and prevent any programmatic access while enabled. You can turn off noscript however, wait until applied, then update the property bag and then disable. I believe this is actually exposed as property 'DenyAddAndCustomizePages' and does take a few seconds to fully disable.

Answer (score 0):

@Mariusz Ignatowicz

Just Test you code in my SPO modern site, It works fine here:

[image]

Then I enabled `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` as @m1g suggested, it will prompt "Access denied. You do not have permissio...."

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

Get-SPOSite -Identity https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/comm|select DenyAddAndCustomizePages
### o is disable, 1 is enable
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/comm -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 1
```

So i think you need to turn off `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` first, then it should be fixed.

BR

Comment: 3 years later, I'm having the same error message, but this time using SharePoint with Azure. Granting the app user the SharePoint Administrator role didn't help. Would you mind taking a look at this and advising?